# How to design an algorithm to determine how many numbers are in a string?

Tags: algorithm

Design an algorithm to determine how many numbers are in a string. Example, given the string "Hello people from the 4 worlds, this is my only 1 program", the output must be 2.

Comment: what language? Stackoverflow is only for technical questions. Add more debugging details (you attempt code)

Comment: @DevCl9 `Design an algorithm` - language is not specified but I guess @Petrus Onesmum is loooking for algorithm/idea, not for code in specific language.

Comment: It's not on-topic with stackoverflow then. It must not be answered here.

Comment: It is, in my opinion. That's why we have `algorithm` tag on StackOverflow.

Comment: If It had some code and Op is stuck on some specific thing, yes. If all theoretical and no code, I don't think so. That's why you'll always find `algorithm` tag along with other language tags and not alone

Comment: @Michu93 I could be wrong, but that's my understanding

Comment: I agree that @PetrusOnesmus should provide some more details - where he stuck or which part he can't solve however I don't agree algorithms must always go with language - algorithms don't have language, algorithm is a recipe how to do something, doesn't matter if you implement it in Java, C, C++ or whatever

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to write a simple parser to parse out the numbers in your string.  To do that you need to be able to recognise a number correctly, which is a little more complicated than just recognising digits.  Something like "-12,348.971" is a number, but contains the characters -,. which are not digits.  However, the string "-,." is not itself a number.

Read through the string, character by character.  When the parser finds the start of a number, count one more number found, and read through all the characters that form that number.  Read '123' as a single number, not three numbers.  When you reach the end of the number skip over non-number characters until either you find the next number or you reach the end of the file.

You might want to read up on writing a simple parser in the language of your choice.

Comment: do you mind sharing your email, i want to ask you something

Comment: I'm afraid I do mind.  Better ask it here.